# Domain specific rewrite rule matches other domains as well

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a couple of domains hosted in a server, and I have a `.htaccess` file similar to this:

```
# FIRST.COM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.first\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.first\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=%2  [L,QSA,NC]

# there are some more rules for first.com here ...

# SECOND.COM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.second\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.second\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=%2  [L,QSA,NC]

# there are some more rules for second.com here ...

# THIRD.COM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.third\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.third\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=%2  [L,QSA,NC]
```

Basically all the domains are pointing out to a single script, however they have slightly different rewrite rules.

I just add the third.com rules now and I realized that all the websites (even those doesn't have any rewrite rule in the .htaccess file) now are going to the third.com.

The third.com rules are exactly in the bottom of the .htaccess file and if I remove them all the above rules will work perfectly fine. There are bunch of rules for first and second domains and they all works fine and they do whatever expected, but when I'm adding those four lines, nothing would match any rules and all requests would match the third.com rule.

Anybody knows how should I debug this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know that `http://fourth.com/abc` is going to `third.com`?

Comment: @anubhava I have slightly different settings for each projects, third.com will gives you yellow-ish color, others are red-ish ...

Comment: Just for testing add `R` flag in all of your `RewriteRule` lines like `[L,QSA,NC,R]` and see what is redirected URL in your browser.

Comment: @anubhava I did it. It's just redirecting to the third domain ... would it be a problem with virtual hosts?

Comment: So now you see `http://third.com/index.php?q=foo` for every URL even when you enter: `http://foo.firstd.com/`?

Comment: @anubhava yes, exactly.

Comment: In that case I suspect there is some redirection happening some where else. It could be in Apache config OR some other .htaccess file

Comment: @anubhava I guess so and thanks anyways for the suggestions :)